Invariant Violation has not been registered. This can happen if: * Metro (the local dev server)
In Reactnative CLI ios getting
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined, js engine: hermes LOG  Running "xxx" with {"rootTag":1,"initialProps":{"concurrentRoot":false}}
ERROR  Invariant Violation: "xxx" has not been registered. This can happen if:

Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
A module failed to load due to an error and AppRegistry.registerComponent wasn't called., js engine: hermes

can any one help me i am getting this error while running ios app in ReactNative
